# Coerce contingency table to report unrepresented classes

Tags: r, contingency-tables

I have a contingency table computed from the out of sample observations. In some cases not all classes are represented in the out of sample and hence do not appear. I want to coerce the contingency table to report zeros for classes not in the out of sample. How can I do it efficiently. For example my contingency table is

```
  x z
x 1 2
y 1 3
z 2 2
```

but i want it to look like

```
  x y z
x 1 0 2
y 1 0 3
z 2 0 2
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R's table function.

Comment: sorry I did not realize I posted on CV while I meant to post to SO. admins please move it to SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the manual.  This is explained in the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/table.html) for `table()`.  You simply set `useNA="ifany"`.

Your edit does not constitute a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536).  If setting the `useNA` argument does not resolve your problem, it may be that R doesn't recognize that that level of your factor exists.  Assuming your column factor is `f.c`, try `f.c <- factor(f.c, levels=c("x","y","z"))` prior to calling `table()`.  If that isn't the solution, you will need to add a truly reproducible example.

Comment: I had tried it but this does not solve my problem. I added some examples to show my problem.